# Can't select row of TableView in QML

Tags: qml, tableview, qitemselectionmodel

I have created a TableView in QML, connected to a SoftFilterProxyModel.  The data displays fine, and when I click on a row my "selectRow" function runs, and receives the correct row number.  However, nothing shows as selected.  I based my design on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566115/purpose-and-usage-of-itemselectionmodel-in-qml)

The relevant code is:

```
ItemSelectionModel {
    id: companyTableISM
    model: companySFPM
}

function selectRow(row) {
    console.log("In selectRow row "+row);
    companyTableISM.select(companySFPM.index(row, 0), ItemSelectionModel.select | ItemSelectionModel.current );
    console.log(companyTableISM.selectedIndexes);
    console.log(companyTableISM.hasSelection);
}
```

So when I click a row it outputs:

```
qml: In selectRow row 3
qml: []
qml: false
```

Since my selectRow function is receiving the correct row number, the model (companySFPM) matches the one used by the TableView, why do my 2 log statements showing nothing selected and false (hasSelection)?

Comment: You should show more code to fully understand what is going on. Nevertheless, could you output `companySFPM.index(row, 0)` and paste what it shows? My guess is that the selection is failing due to the `index()` function failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have two typos in the line:

```
ItemSelectionModel.select | ItemSelectionModel.current
```

Notice the capitalization of the enumerated types?  It should be:

```
ItemSelectionModel.Select | ItemSelectionModel.Current
```

Answer (score 0):

Current and Select are selection flags enum of `select()`. For more selection flags you can read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-itemselectionmodel.html#select-method) .
Replace s and c of select and current with capital letter.

```
companyTableISM.select(companySFPM.index(row, 0), ItemSelectionModel.Select | ItemSelectionModel.Current);
```